# Unable to read character from a networkStream object using StreamReader in C#

Tags: c#, stream

I want to read an array of character from a networkStream object in this way :

```
    public String readLine(NetworkStream networkStream)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(networkStream))//This line throws an exception
        {

            char[] buffer = new char[128];
            int offset = 0;
            int ch;

            while(true)
            {
                ch = reader.Read();
                if (ch == -1 || ch == '\n')
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (ch == '\r')
                {
                    //int tempch = ;
                    if (reader.Peek()== '\n')
                    {
                        break;
                    }
          }
      }
```

When i run the program i get an exception error **"Stream unreadable"**. Is it because the StreamReader constructor expects a stream Object not a networkStream as a parameter ? If yes, is there a workaround or an alternative way of reading characters from a networkStream object?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which line throws the exception?

Comment: More information about `networkStreamObj`'s type and initialisation would be useful.

Comment: With a network stream you should check .CanRead first before trying to access it

Answer (score 3):

You'll get this exception when the stream's CanRead property is false.  We can't tell how you created the NetworkStream, but a logical explanation is that you're trying to read from a network stream that you opened for writing.

Comment: I created the networkStream object from a TcpClient.GetStream() method in a another class.